# Push notifications not showing when app is open pushwoosh - Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, phonegap-build, pushwoosh

I am using Pushwoosh to send notifications in Phonegap however if i am in app the notification doesn't show up both in case of Android and iOS.

How do i resolve this?

I have gone through a few links but haven't been able to figure that out.

```
   function initPushwoosh()
{

    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    if (device.platform == "Android")
    {

        //set push notifications handler
        document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
            var title = event.notification.title;
            var userData = event.notification.userdata;

            if (typeof (userData) != "undefined") {
                console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
            }


        });

        //initialize Pushwoosh with projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER", appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID". This will trigger all pending push notifications on start.
        pushNotification.onDeviceReady({projectid: "", appid: ""});


        //register for pushes
        pushNotification.registerDevice(
                function(status) {
                    var pushToken = status;

                    localStorage.setItem("deviceid", pushToken);

                    console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);
                },
                function(status) {
                    console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
                }
        );



    }
    else if (device.platform == "iOS")
    {
        //set push notification callback before we initialize the plugin
        document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
            //get the notification payload
            var notification = event.notification;
            navigator.notification.alert(notification.aps.alert);


            //clear the app badge
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
        });

        //initialize the plugin
        pushNotification.onDeviceReady({pw_appid: ""});

        //register for pushes
        pushNotification.registerDevice(
                function(status) {
                    var deviceToken = status['deviceToken'];
                    localStorage.setItem("deviceid", deviceToken);




                },
                function(status) {
                    console.warn('failed to register : ' + JSON.stringify(status));

                }
        );


        //reset badges on app start
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
    }
}



function init()
{

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", initPushwoosh, true);
    // document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    // Cordova is ready to be used!
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't show up"?

Comment: Doesn't come as a push notification. If i put a normal javascript alert i receive the text as an alert.

Comment: This is default behavior for iOS. When you are in the app (the app is in the foreground) push notifications goes directly to the app bypassing notification center. This cannot be changed.

Android mimics this behavior. This could be changed (please submit a feature request on github).

Answer (score 1):

Use force show

```
var push = PushNotification.init(
     { "android": {"senderID": "533867441597", "forceShow": "true"
             },
  "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"
         } 

});
```